# python3.6: gdal.Open('*.tif') succeed, but ReadAsArray() got 'NoneType' error

Tags: python, gdal

I'm using `gdal` to read `jp2` by lines, here is the code:

```
def open(self):
    if self.ds is None:
        self.ds = gdal.Open(self.file_path, gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
        self.geo_transform = self.ds.GetGeoTransform()
        self.rows = self.ds.RasterYSize
        self.cols = self.ds.RasterXSize

def read_strip(self, y_start, read_y_size):
    """
    y_start : y in projection coordinate
    """
    self.open()
    if not self.ds:
        raise IOError("Could not open '%s'" % self.file_path)

    y_off = int((y_start - self.geo_transform[3]) / self.geo_transform[5])
    if y_off < 0 or y_off >= self.rows:
        return None
    else:
        read_y_size_in_data = min(self.rows - y_off, read_y_size)

        try:
            read_data = self.ds.ReadAsArray(0, y_off, ysize=read_y_size_in_data)
            band_data = read_data.astype(float)
            self.logger.info('{}, {}, {}'.format(read_y_size, y_off, read_y_size_in_data))
            return band_data
        except Exception:
            self.logger.exception('this file is Nonetype, file: {}'.format(self.file_path))

            self.logger.info('{}, {}, {}'.format(read_y_size, y_off, read_y_size_in_data))
    self.close()
```

Here is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "scene_reader.py", line 62, in read_strip band_data = read_data.astype(float), 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'astype'
```

Every time I run the code, I did not get any IOError, which means the jp2 file is opened successfully, while the ReadAsArray() got an 'Nonetype' error. by the way, I have tried to just use gdal.Open() and ReadAsArray() to read the same file by several lines in ipython, everything is ok, so, I'm pretty sure there is nothing wrong with the jp2 file itself.
so, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to pick a band, even if it is a single band data set.  `ds.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()` like that.  I always refer to this [GDAL API Tutorial](https://gdal.org/tutorials/raster_api_tut.html) which has simple examples.